# How do I deal with an Ember component that needs third-party javascript that I want to load async?

Tags: ember.js

I want to load the google maps API. Normally I would do this:

```
<script>function readyGoogleMaps(){/* stuff */}</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.21&callback=readyGoogleMaps"></script>
```

In Ember I've instead created two components. One which loads google maps and one which renders google maps after it's loaded.

**/components/google-map.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  mapsLoaded: false,
  init(){
    this._super(...arguments);
    window.readyGoogleMaps = () =>{
      delete window.readyGoogleMaps;
      this.set('mapsLoaded', true);
      console.log("Loaded");
    };
    Ember.$.getScript("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.21&callback=readyGoogleMaps");
  }
});
```

**/components/real-google-maps.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  map: null,
  didInsertElement(){
    const map = new google.maps.Map(this.$()[0], {
    });
    this.set('map', map);
  }
});
```

This is of course not ideal, because google maps don't start loading until the component is rendered and I end up having to glue my component. How should a component in Ember deal with needing third-party javascript that I can't be sure is available when the component is called?

Comment: I would make a service for this,

Answer (score 1):

You can load it in an instance initializer, and defer app readiness until the script has been loaded.

If you want to lazy load it, you can create a service inject it into the route and call the load method when you need it.

There is a ember-cli-addon for google maps. it uses the lazy load strategy. instead of using a service the addon manually registers the function with all routes

[Lazyload function](https://github.com/huafu/ember-google-map/blob/master/addon/utils/load-google-map.js)

[Manual injection logic](https://github.com/huafu/ember-google-map/blob/master/app/initializers/ember-google-map.js)